# i'am Getting This error. Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '- Select -' to data type int. My Code Is Given below

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

[This Is my Sql table Structure so maybe its details what Is Problem Is...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B8Cm.png)
[This is the problem Iam getting In website](http://tvtalks.in/RealityShows.aspx)

I am getting Error In this code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Getreality();
            GetAds();
        }
    }

    private void Getreality()
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Getallreality", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Reality Show";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        ListViewSerials.DataSource = dt;
        ListViewSerials.DataBind();
        conn.Close();
    }

    protected void DataPager1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Getreality();
    }
```

Comment: Where's the SQL?

Comment: You execute a stored procedure named "Getallreality" . The conversion problem probably occurs there

Comment: How have you defined `ListViewSerials` in aspx? Which line is throwing error?

Comment: That's a SQL Server error message so the error is in the SQL, which we can't see here. Almost certainly though, it's an attempt to construct a string using `+` for concatenation but whilst there's a string on one side, the thing on the other side is an `int`, and data type precedence means SQL wants to do `int` addition.

Comment: Seems `- Select -` is an initial value you want to show with DDL, why not using a `ListItem` inside `DropDownList`: `<asp:ListItem Text="- Select -" Value="" />`? The rest of DDL data can be fetched afterwards.

Comment: Again, the problem is in the *SQL Code* that is running inside the stored procedure you're calling. Whilst the table definition is welcome (although as a copy & paste-able `CREATE TABLE` statement in text would be better), it's not going to help us in helping you.

Comment: thanks for all ans. i solved It

Comment: it would be nice if you added your solution, so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are going great. After watching your piece of code i have realized you are using SqlDbType.NVarChar to send the value to your parameter used in your stored procedure. But unfortunately your SP (stored procedure) need the varchar or nvarchar parameter to accept with the same definition as of your table have.

You need to check the parameter @type and its datatype and change it to nvarchar. also check the table definition it would be same as datatype.

PS - If you are converting the parameter values in query then you can use
`CAST(@your_Parameter_Name AS nvarchar(15))` would an alternative to resolve your concern.

Could you send the SP and table definition. I will give you the more precise solution.

Comment: payal8772@gmail.com its my mail can u pls Help

Comment: i pinged you on hangout. please share your screen i will help.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it cant convert the nvarchar value '- Select -' to int .Which is because '- Select -' is not a valid int value.
Exclude that value from your SQL or post your SQL here for help

Comment: iam added a pic Of Sql Tabel maybe Its help to Understand u thank u

Answer (score 0):

Error caught in stored procedure That A Line Notnull was null Thats why Iam Geting that Error
I Check Table and fixed It